# C# Selenium AADSTS90100: login parameter is empty or not valid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, dynamics-crm

I'm creating a method for logging in to MS Dynamics 365 and get the error below when RUN the test:

> AADSTS90100: login parameter is empty or not valid.

Here is my code:

```
public void Login(SecureString login, SecureString password)
{
   _driver.Url = "https://{domain}.crm4.dynamics.com/";
   _driver.WaitForPageToLoad(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   var userNameInput = _driver.WaitUntilAvailable(By.CssSelector("input[type = 'email']"), 
                                                  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   userNameInput.SendKeys(login.ToUnsecureString());
   var submitButton = _driver.WaitUntilClickable(By.CssSelector("input[type = 'submit'][value = 
                                                 'Next']"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   submitButton.Click();
   //userNameInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

   // following actions
}
```

I also tried sending the Enter key and Submit() method but no luck.
Interesting thing - I cannot reproduce the issue manually or when DEBUG the test. The error appears only in the RUN mode of the test.

I compared URLs in RUN and DEBUG modes and there is not any difference.

I spent 3 hours in Google but didn't find a solution.
It should be mentioned, that I'm not an experienced dev. So can miss or don't understand something.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root cause.
Actually, the issue occurs not after `submitButton.Click();` but after another action which is not provided here, since the error message is a bit confusing.

The thing is we used EasyRepro framework in our solution and getting rid of it now since it's not been supported for more than a year now.

If we take a look at EasyRepro login logic, there is such a method:

```
private static void EnterPassword(IWebDriver driver, SecureString password)
{
   var input = 
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Elements.Xpath[Reference.Login.LoginPassword]));
   input.SendKeys(password.ToUnsecureString());
   input.Submit();
}
```

And the error is caused by `input.Submit();` line. I just copied it in my new method.

It seems like the method submits the whole form before the login has time to be written somewhere.

So, I simply changed that to this one:

```
private bool EnterPassword(string password)
{
   var passwordInput = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type = 
                                           'password']"));
   passwordInput.SendKeys(password);

   var submitButton = _driver.WaitUntilClickable(By.CssSelector("input[type = 
                                                 'submit'][value = 'Sign in']"), 
                                                 _defaultWait);
   submitButton.Click();

   var staySignedInDialog = _driver.WaitUntilAvailable(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(), 'Stay signed 
                              in?')]"), _defaultWait);

   return staySignedInDialog != null;
}
```

Hope will be useful for someone in the future.